# Locate duplicates with a temp table

Tags: duplicates, temp-tables

I am trying to locate all valid/ non expired duplicate ids from a temp table that is created. When I run this script I get 240,000 results. Only about half of the results are duplicates (when transferring them over into excel) What am I missing to get only duplicate results.

I have tried looking in previous questions about duplicates and none of them have worked. The `HAVING COUNT (E.ID_NUMBER) > 1` seems to be a common way to do it.

My knowledge is limited in the use of temp tables and not sure if that has something to do with why I am not getting the results need.

I have tried putting the `HAVING COUNT(E.ID_NUMBER) > 1` in the 2nd part of the script and only get about 700 results (there should be more than this)

Any help/ suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDb..#DUPLICATE_ID') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DUPLICATE_ID ;
CREATE TABLE #DUPLICATE_ID
    (ID CHAR(9))
INSERT INTO 
      #DUPLICATE_ID
SELECT
      distinct
      E.ID_NUMBER 
FROM 
      EXAMPLEDb..ENROLLEES E
WHERE
      E.ID_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
      E.ID_NUMBER 
HAVING 
      COUNT(E.ID_NUMBER) > 1

-----------------------------------------------

SELECT 
    DI.ID, E.LAST_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME, E.ADDRESS1, E.CITY, E.STATE, E.ZIP
FROM 
    EXAMPLEDb..ENROLLEES E
    LEFT JOIN #DUPLICATE_ID DI ON E.ID_NUMBER = DI.ID
WHERE 
    DI.ID IS NOT NULL
    and is null(e.TERMINATION_DATE,'1/1/2020')  > '4/27/2016' 
group BY 
    DI.ID, E.LAST_NAME, E.FIRST_NAME, E.ADDRESS1, E.CITY, E.STATE, E.ZIP
```